# RegEx in Java for multiple hits

Tags: java, regex

The Input String contains multiple occurrences of "pageref" and "time"
Give me a regex in java or source code in java to extract their values from the input string. A part of the input string is given below.

**Input String :**

```
 "entries": [
  {
    "pageref": "page_0",
    "startedDateTime": "2014-07-21T21:08:37.491+05:30",
    "time": 515,
    "request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "cookies": [],
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Host",
          "value": "www.facebook.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "User-Agent",
          "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept",
          "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept-Language",
          "value": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept-Encoding",
          "value": "gzip, deflate"
        },
        {
          "name": "Connection",
          "value": "keep-alive"
        }
      ],
```

**Output Required :**

```
page_0 515
```

Comment: Is is JSON string? if yes then use JSON parser. why you are choosing regex.

Comment: The entire Input String is given below :

Comment: I am asking from you. is it JSON string?

Comment: *Give me a regex in java or source code in java*, not a good way to ask someone

Comment: "*Give me a regex in java or source code in java to extract their values from the input string*" that is not how Stack Overflow works. Here it is **you** who is responsible for creating code. We are here in case you will have problems with it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP asked for a regular expression for a non-regular grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [JSON library](http://json.org/java/)

sample code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject innJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("entries").getJSONObject(0);
System.out.println(innJsonObject.get("pageref")); // page_0
System.out.println(innJsonObject.get("time"));    // 515
```

You can try with [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library as well.

sample code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>> data = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
Map<String, Object> map = data.get("entries").get(0);
System.out.println(map.get("pageref"));  // page_0
System.out.println(map.get("time"));     // 515.0
```

This is the valid JSON string:

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "pageref": "page_0",
            "startedDateTime": "2014-07-21T21: 08: 37.491+05: 30",
            "time": 515,
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "url": "https: //www.facebook.com/",
                "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
                "cookies": [],
                "headers": [
                    {
                        "name": "Host",
                        "value": "www.facebook.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "User-Agent",
                        "value": "Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.1;rv: 30.0)Gecko/20100101Firefox/30.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Accept",
                        "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Accept-Language",
                        "value": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                        "value": "gzip,deflate"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Connection",
                        "value": "keep-alive"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried with JSON. Will try and let you know

Comment: @Braj...No Luck .I have HAR (HTTP Archive File ) Log file, from which I wnated to extract "pageref" and "time" values.

Comment: have you tried with GSON library. I have posted valid json string as well. What fails let me know?

Comment: try first with the json that I have shared in the answer that is valid json string.

Comment: here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qR4rR7/4) if you are looking for regex.

Comment: Error : The method getJSONArray(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject 
public class JsonSimpleExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
 
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 
  Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Downloads\\_har\\www.facebook.com+2014-07-21+21-08-43.json"));
  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
  JSONObject innJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("entries").getJSONObject(0);
  System.out.println(innJsonObject.get("pageref")); // page_0
  System.out.println(innJsonObject.get("time"));
 
     } 
}

Comment: are you using [this library](http://json.org/java/)

Comment: Thank You. Regex helped me solve my problm.